# How to position a TextView in a layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to design this kind of layout, which will have a title and a background image as shown in the below image, and three `TextView`s at the center of each separator. When one of the `TextView`s text size increases, the other `TextView`s will remain at the same position.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#0D181E" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <view 
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
         <view 
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

U can drag and drop in xml file has your wish but advise is use relative layout. it may be use full some scenarios